# React redux provider grand child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main js file, let's say:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {Provider}  from 'react-redux';
import {store}  from './store.js';
import {App} from './app.js'

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,      document.getElementById('content'));
```

And my App.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Proba } from './proba.js'

export class App extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }

    render()
    {
        return (<div><button>Success</button><Proba /></div>);
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(store)
{
    return {
        a: 'ok'
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch)
{
    return {};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

How can i reach store from the Proba component? I can get it in App, but don't know how can i pass it down to childs of it.

I tried the following but doesn't work, i still get an empty object in my proba.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Proba extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props);
    }


    render()
    {
        return <p>{this.props.a}</p>;
    }
}

function anotherMapStateToProps(store)
{
    return {
        a: 'ok'
    };
}

function anoterMapDispatchToProps(dispatch)
{
    return {};
}

export default connect(anotherMapStateToProps, anoterMapDispatchToProps)(Proba)
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way as you did for `App`. `connect()` it and pick the values of the store you would like to pass into the component as props.

```
export default connect(anotherMapStateToProps, anoterMapDispatchToProps)(Proba)
```

Comment: I tried it, updated my question. Changed nothing in my app.js, should i?